# axios.post().then() not passing resolved data to callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When I use `axios.post(...).then(data=>callback(data))` the data is not defined when I access it in the callback, however, a console log right before the data is accessed shows all the data.

I've tried all the combinations of async await that's possible. I feel like this is a way simpler problem than I'm making it.

```
// passed in as successCallback
const handleCreationCompleted = data => {
    console.log(data)

    // Error below ReturnedDataObject not defined
    var object = data.ReturnedDataObject

}

const createObject = async (variables, successCallback, errorCallback) => {
    ...
    await axios.post(url, form_data, {
        headers: {
    ...
        },
    }).then(res => {
        successCallback(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        errorCallback(err)
    })
```

I should be able to access the data, which is a json object (it's fetched from a graphql api) within the successcallback

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you get from the console.log?

Comment: @MattAft This suggestion lead to me realising I had to access a chain of data.data.data, the way the promises were chained and how graphql returns the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `await` with `then()`. You should switch to one. If you use await, assign the result to a variable. You should also be passing back the data of the response and not the response itself.

```
const response = await axios.post(...)
callback(response.data)
```

If you want to use `then`, then it's:

```
axios.post(...)
.then(respone => callback(response.data))
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. If you `console.log(data)` from inside that callback, the data is returned. However if you try to access it, there's an error. I.e. it's the exact same behaviour as the code I have above.

Comment: What's the error exactly? Just that the variable is undefined?

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ReturnedDataObject' of undefined`

Comment: You should be passing back `res.data`, not `res`. Updated answer.

Comment: This solved it, moving from apollo request to axios request required this change.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!